# Maximum singular value of matrix-valued function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, singular-values

Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be two given $n\times n$ matrices. Consider the following matrix-valued function, which maps an arbitrary $n\times n$ unitary matrix $U$ to
\begin{equation}
f(U)=U H_1 U^\dagger + i H_2
\end{equation}
Given any $n\times n$ matrix $M$, define $\sigma_1(M)$ to be the greatest singular value of $M$.

**Question**: find $\underset{U}{\text{max}}\;\sigma_1(f(U))$.

Comment: What is $U^{\dagger}$?

Comment: It denotes the Hermitian conjugate, i.e. the conjugate transpose of $U$. Mathematicians probably denote it more often by a star.

Comment: FWIW, I would advise you to add some context to your question. A question like this is very likely to be ignored or closed.